# Javascript execution context & variables in V8

Tags: javascript, v8, executioncontext

I know the V8 is consist of Memory Heap and Call Stack

The execution context is located in the call stack.
Global variables exist in the global execution context, and local variables exist in each execution context.

The reference type identifier is also located in the execution context. Even though the actual data exists in the heap area

question 1

**If so, is it correct to think that all identifiers are on the call stack because they are in the execution context?**

question 2

**Where will the real primitive data like 25 be?**